# In Hive, can't select fields from existing table and create a new table. Why?

Tags: hive

I'm trying to extract data from an existing Hive table and create a new Hive table but the following query returns 0 rows.  Is the syntax wrong?  What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE prod_grdw.bandcards AS 
   SELECT
       ds,
       experiment,
       layer,
       variant,
       user_browser_id,
       user_uuid
   FROM prod_grdw.bld_experiments 
   WHERE experiment = 'us-special'
     AND ds between '20151201' AND '20151202';
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"returns 0 rows"*?? A `create table as` DDL command does not return any row. It just says OK / Error.

Comment: Could you post the result of the following query :

    SELECT experiment, ds from prod_grdw.bld_experiments LIMIT 10 

It should print 4 rows, but it may give us an idea of what's wrong with the data/table. Most likely, the data is not how you are expecting it to be.